# VBA VarType in Match Function

Tags: vba, excel

I am attempting to use the excel vba function Application.Match

The match function will only work with my first array arrCompare(0) and arrCompare(5). Microsoft says the variables passed to the function must be variants. This statement doesn't seem to be entirely true as arrCompare(0) & arrCompare(5) are strings and  arrCompare(1) is a string. I haven't yet understood why the Match function does not work when the forumla gets to the remaining arrCompare(1,2,3,4) variables.

```
Dim arrCompare(5) as Variant
Dim intRow As Integer
Dim varRes As Double

Set sht = ActiveSheet
Set shtTigers = Worksheets("Tigers").Range("A5:A10000")
Set shtElephants = Worksheets("Elephants").Range("A6:A10000")

Sheets("Elephants").Activate

For intRow = 6 To 7

arrCompare(0) = Worksheets("Elephants").Cells(intRow, 1).Value      'varType(arrCompare(0)) = 8
arrCompare(1) = Worksheets("Elephants").Cells(intRow, 2).Value      'varType(arrCompare(1)) = 8
arrCompare(2) = Worksheets("Elephants").Cells(intRow, 4).Value      'varType(arrCompare(2)) = 8
arrCompare(3) = Worksheets("Elephants").Cells(intRow, 5).Value      'varType(arrCompare(3)) = 8
arrCompare(4) = Worksheets("Elephants").Cells(intRow, 7).Value      'varType(arrCompare(4)) = 8
arrCompare(5) = Worksheets("Elephants").Cells(intRow, 9).Value      'varType(arrCompare(5)) = 8

'I intend to use this function to compare all 6 array variables but for now am stuck getting 1 at a time to work
varRes = Application.Match(arrCompare(0), shtTigers, 0)
```

Any input on where my script is wrong or causing an error are appreciated.

Comment: varRes must be Variant because Application.Match can return number or error value

Comment: FWIW - a `Variant/String` is a `Variant`, so there is nothing wrong with your first parameter.  (And because a normal `String` can be coerced to a `Variant/String`, you could even pass variables declared `As String` as the first parameter of the `Match` function.)

Comment: @Slai `varRes` doesn't **have** to be `Variant`, but it **should** be `Variant` so that there is no "type mismatch" caused by trying to coerce a error value to a `Double` if the value isn't found in the search area.

Comment: What have you declared `shtTigers` as?  Is that a `Variant`? a `Range`?
 something else?

Comment: And, most importantly (because this looks like a data error), what is the value of `arrCompare(1)` when it crashes, and does that value exist in the range `Tigers!A5:A10000`?

Comment: shtTigers has not been declared.I have: Dim sht As Worksheet if that is your question. The value of arrCompare(1) is the value of the cell it is set to, in this case a value of "16058/1". Yes this value exists on the Tigers worksheet.

Comment: And I would expect the application.match to give me the row number where the match occured (e.g. row 5).

Comment: The error given is Run-time Error '13' Type Mismatch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

varRes must be Variant because Application.Match can return number or error value